# Pseudocode for a CPP project

Tags: c++, pseudocode

I am trying to learn how to pseudocode. Could you please check my work and see if this is the correct way to develop a pseudo-code?

**The problem is this:**

"Write a program to ask the user for a series of test scores of students. The compute and print the  test scores arithmetic mean for each student"

**Here is my Pseudo-Code:**

1. prompt user for studentNum
2. prompt for testNum
3. start while loop to collect data:
   while (i < studentNum)

   3.1 ask for studentName

   3.2 set sum to zero

   3.3 start second nested while loop
      while (j < testNum)

   ```
     3.3.1. ask user for the testScore

     3.3.2. collect data using sum variable.
   ```

   3.4 compute average by dividing sum by testNum

   3.5 display data in the format:

   "For " << studentName << "The average test score was: " << average

Thank you

Comment: edit to fix your formatting please

Comment: sorry, did not proof read..will fix right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still looks a little too much like real code to me. There's no *point* in being too specific, you might as well write real code.

Instead of `while i < studentNum`, say `repeat studentNum times`.

Instead of `output in the format ... << ... <<`, say `Display output like: For John Doe, average was 75.0.`

Edit: here is full pseudocode that I would write:

- input `n`, the number of students
- input `t`, the number of tests per student
- for each student:

  - for each test, input and accumulate
  - divide this student's sum by number of tests
  - output like `For John Doe, average was 75.0`

Comment: looks good. What about the rest please?